# RabbitMq on Docker connection fail

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, pika

Im learning basics of RabbitMQ,  installed it on a container.
When inspecting the container it seems ok .

```
PS C:\Users\jvidin> docker port rabbitmq
25672/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32776
4369/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32779
5671/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32778
5672/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32777
PS C:\Users\jvidin> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                 NAMES
d2fe1297c403        rabbitmq:latest     "docker-entrypoint..."   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:32779->4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32778->5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32776->25672/tcp   rabbitmq
55253e21bb49        b38ce49eadce        "docker-entrypoint..."   8 weeks ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp                                                                                mypostgres9.6
```

But than when trying to connect via Pika Python lib as below it fails with message below

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: timeout
```

Code

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

RESOLUTION BELOW CORRECT CONNECTION INFO

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=32777))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your python client to use `localhost:32777`.

Just check the output of `docker port rabbitmq`. It shows that container port `5672` is mapped to port `32777` on your docker host.